# ELK stack custom fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am quite new to ELK stack and trying to add custom fields in filebeats.

I have siebel error codes present in message field, i am trying to create a custom field for error code to be displayed as a separate field in kibana dashboard. Below is the filebeat.yml file config and the fields are not displaying on Kibana dashboard. Could anyone please guide where am I going wrong or how can I make this work.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
   -  C:\Users\parinita.vinod\Documents\logs\SCCObjMgr_enu_SubmitOrder_Masked\*

  fields:
    error_code: SBL-EXL-00145
  fields_under_root: true 

output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["0.0.0.0:5044"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved. I deleted the filebeat.yml file and re-created after which it started to work. Above configuration is working fine now.